# Browser Automation testing

Tags: browser, browser-automation

I have browser automation framework which is using Selenium Web Driver.It currently runs all the tests which I have in an excel with commands which the framework understands and generates reports  with snapshots.

What else can I do with the Selenium? Like what other features can be added to improve testing?

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and implement Page Objects pattern in you selenium automation framework.
It will make your test more robust, scalable and easy to maintain.
To read more about it, with guides and examples, try [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/08/09/selenium-2web-driver-land-where-page-objects-are-king), and [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory).